# Roots in $\mathbb{Z}_m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Suppose we define $S_m\subseteq \mathbb{Z}_m[x]$ to be the set of all polynomials $f$ that has roots everywhere in $\mathbb{Z}_m$, i.e. $f(a)=0$ for all $a\in \mathbb{Z}_m$.

It is immediate by FLT that $x^p-x\in S_p$, and that every element of $S_p$ is in fact a multiple of $x^p-x$. Now, $S_6$ will contain elements with degree $3$ and $2$. Do these two examples generate $S_6$? How would we prove or disprove this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ Note that $\ 2,3\mid f(n) = n^3\!-n = (n\!-\!1)n(n\!+\!1)\ $ for all $\,n,\,$ so $\,6\mid f(n)\,$ for all $\,n\,$ i.e. $\,f(x) = \,x^3\!-x = 0\,$ as a *function* on $\,\Bbb Z_6.$ Using $\,x^3\! = x\,$ as a rewrite rule we can reduce all powers of $\,x\,$ to powers $\le 2,\,$ so any polynomial function is equal to a polynomial function of degree $\le 2.\,$ However, these reduced polynomials are not all distinct functions, e.g. note that  $\ 3x^2 = 3x\ $ since their difference $\,3x(x\!-\!1)\, $ is the zero function on $\,\Bbb Z_6,\,$ since $\,2\mid n(n\!-\!1).\,$

**Remark** $\ $ One can generalize the above analysis to obtain an axiomatization of the identities satsified by any fixed list of finite *fields* - see the following, excerpted from Stanley Burris and John Lawrence, [Term rewrite rules for finite fields (1991).](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.85.9115) For example, the Lemma below implies that any polynomial identity that holds true in $\,\Bbb F_4,\,\Bbb F_9,\,\Bbb F_{25}\,$ is an equational consequence of

$$\begin{eqnarray} 30 = 0,\ \  & 15(x^4-x) = 0\\
x^{25}\! = x,\ \  & 10(x^9-x) = 0\\
         & \ 6(x^{25}-x) = 0\end{eqnarray}$$

---

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had a reason to dig up the history of this problem once. A solution has been published many times:

- I. Niven and L. J. Warren, "A Generalization of Fermat's Theorem", Proc. Amer. Math. Soc., vol. 8, no. 2, pp. 306-313, April 1957.
- D. Singmaster, "On Polynomial Functions (mod m)", J. Number Theory,
  pp. 345-352, 1974.

Even earlier Carlitz studied necessary and sufficient criteria for a function from $\Bbb{Z}_m$ to itself to come from a polynomial with integer coefficients. He remarked that a description of the set $S_m$ was a guided exercise in Dickson's textbook from 1910s. I haven't checked but I have no reason to suspect that. Anyway, this problem has been solved and forgotten periodically.

A quick summary.The set $S_m$ is clearly an ideal in $\Bbb{Z}_m[x]$. Chinese remainder theorem is your friend, and allows you to reduce the problem to the case where $m$ is a power of a prime number. Bill's answer (+1) is on the money in the sense that descending factorials are the key. After all
$$
r_k(x):=x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots (x-k+1)=k!\binom{x}{k}
$$
manifestly vanishes modulo $k!$.

Here's how we use that. As an example let's do $m=2^{10}$. The following polynomials belong to the ideal $S_m$ and generate it (not trivial, but not exceedingly hard either - search for those papers for the details):

- the values of $r_2(x)$ are all even, so $2^9r_2(x)\in S_{1024}$,
- the values of $r_4(x)$ are all divisible by $4!$, hence by $8$, so $2^7r_4(x)\in S_{1024}$,
- the values of $r_6(x)$ are all divisible by $6!$, hence by $2^4$, so $2^6r_6(x)\in S_{1024}$,
- the values of $r_8(x)$ are all divisible by $8!$, hence by $2^7$, so $2^3r_8(x)\in S_{1024}$,
- similarly we see that $2^2r_{10}(x)\in S_{1024}$,
- and finally we see that as $2^{10}\mid 12!$, the values of $r_{12}(x)$ are all divisible by $2^{10}$. Thus the MONIC polynomial $r_{12}(x)\in S_{1024}$, and therefore in the quotient ring $\Bbb{Z}_{1024}[x]/S_{1024}$ all the cosets have a representative of degree $<12$.

Similarly with other primes $p$, we can use the polynomials $r_{jp}(x)$ and need to figure out (that is easy) the exact power of $p$ that divides $(jp)!$.

Comment: In the case $m=6$ Bill's answer gives everything. The ideal $S_6$ is generated by $r_3(x)$ and $3r_2(x)$.

Comment: Alas, I couldn't recall the Carlitz reference. But I've added a reference to the interesting related case of varieties of finite fields - see the edit to my answer.

Comment: I couldn't find the Carlitz reference or the Dickson exercise, but at the other [linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4070051), some related references found [via OEIS](https://oeis.org/A058067) are mentioned, though it's not this problem exactly: Kempner, 1921, "Polynomials and their residue systems" ([1](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1921-022-02/S0002-9947-1921-1501173-4/home.html), [2](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1921-022-03/S0002-9947-1921-1501174-6/home.html)); David Singmaster, 1974, [On polynomial functions (mod m)](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-314X(74)90031-6)).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR You are correct about me having misdated Singmaster's article. Thank you. I just checked my old article where these calculations were used, and, unfortunately, we decided to leave out the reference to Carlitz's article back in the day. IIRC he was studying a slightly different problem. If I relocate it, I will, of course, add it here.

Answer (score 1):

This question was linked from my (2021) question [How many "distinct" polynomial functions are there mod ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4070051/how-many-distinct-polynomials-functions-are-there-mod-n). The theorem proved there gives a characterization of the set $S_m$ from this question, of [polynomials that induce the zero function mod $m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3387540/polynomials-that-induce-the-zero-function-mod-n/4070878#4070878):

> the polynomials that induce the zero function mod $m$ are precisely those that, when written in the form
> $$f(x) = \sum_{k} c_k x^{\underline k},$$
> satisfy the property that $c_k$ is divisible by $m\,/\gcd(m, k!)$, for each $k$. (Here, $x^{\underline k}$ is the "falling factorial": $x^{\underline k} = x(x-1)\cdots(x-k+1)$.)

In particular for $m = 6$, we need $c_2$ to be divisible by $3$, so apart from the zero polynomial, the only other polynomial of degree $2$ that corresponds to the zero function is $3x^{\underline 2} = 3x(x-1)$. And the coefficients $c_3$ and higher can be arbitrary, as $x^{\underline 3}$ is always divisible by $6$.