# Algebraic and transcendental functions over $\mathbb Z_n$ -- is this a known result?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, finite-rings

I have proved a result that seems (to me) interesting, and I am wondering whether it is a known result, and if not whether it seems interesting to others.  The result is as follows:

Let $R=\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$ and let $\mathcal A = R^R$ denote the algebra of functions from $R$ to itself.  Then:

> 1. If $n$ is prime, every function in $\mathcal A$ can be represented by a unique polynomial in $R[x]$ of degree at most $n-1$; more
>      specifically, there exists a natural isomorphism $R[x]/(x^n-x) \cong
>     \mathcal A$.
> 2. If $n$ is composite, then most functions in $\mathcal A$ cannot be represented by any polynomial in $R[x]$; that is, the natural
>      homomorphism $R[x] \to \mathcal A$ is not onto.

Is this a well-known result?  A trivial one?  It certainly seemed interesting to me when I came across it, and I have been unsuccessful in finding any statement of this online.

Just to clarify, I am not asking for a proof -- I have one already -- just for an assessment of the value of the result.

Comment: [A related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/789219/11619). See the answers by Bill Dubuque and yours truly. Not an exact duplicate, but close enough to prevent me from answering this with a clear conscience.

Comment: IMO the simplest argument showing that you cannot get all the functions from polynomials is the following. If $p$ is a prime divisor of $n$, $n$ composite, then all the polynomials $f$ with coefficients in $R$ will satisfy $$a\equiv b\pmod p\implies f(a)\equiv f(b)\pmod p.$$ IIRC in a paper by Carlitz there is a description of the set of functions that you get by evaluating polynomials.

Comment: The fact that every function from $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ to itself is a polynomial when $n$ is prime is something that I think of as well known because I know it and because the proof is obvious, but I haven't taken any poll of mathematicians to see how many are aware of it. The other point I don't recall having thought of before.  However, if you call a function algebraic, I am at first inclined to think it means the function somehow is a zero of a polynomial, rather than that the function itself is a polynomial function. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's certainly well-known. It is an immediate corollary of the Chinese Remainder Theorem. Notice that you could also work with $R^S$ for any finite set $S$. (And you don't mean $R^R$, which doesn't exist; you mean $R^S$, where $S$ is the underlying set of the ring $R$.)