# Evaluated polynomials over finite rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, finite-fields

**Hypothesis :**

Let $R$ be a finite commutative ring with unity.

Two polynomials $P,Q \in R[X]$ are said to be equivalent over $R$ if :
$$\forall r \in R, P(r)=Q(r).$$
If so, we note $P \sim Q$.

**My question :** is it true that every element from $R[X]/\sim$ can be represented by a polynomial with degree less than $|R|$ ?
Is $R[X]/\sim$ still a ring ?

**My thoughts :** the answer seems to be positive if $R$ is a field and $|R|=p$, $p$ being prime, thanks to Frobenius' endomorphism. Indeed, for such a ring, $ \forall r \in R, r^{|R|}=r$. Then it is easy to reduce every polynomial to a representative with degree less than $|R|$.

If $R$ is an integral domain, then $R$ is a commutative field. Thus $|R|=p^n$ with $p$ prime and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

The case $n=1$ has already been done. But i'm already blocked when $n>1$ and have absolutely no idea how to tackle the question entirely. May be it has something to do with Euclidean domains ?

Thank you.

Comment: The remark I want to make is that one can often do a bit better. The case of $R=\Bbb{Z}_n$ is a well studied one. Chinese remainder theorem reduces it to the prime power case in general, and falling factorials give you the result. It's  a bit too long to write out fully, but the following example gives you a taste of it. Consider the case $n=2^3$. The values of the polynomial $f_4(x)=x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$ when $x\in\Bbb{Z}$ are all divisible by $4!=2^3\cdot3$. Therefore any polynomial in $\Bbb{Z}_8[x]$ is $\sim$ to a polynomial of degree $<4$.

Comment: For more details about the case of $\Bbb{Z}_n$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/789404/11619).

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen, thank you for those interesting precisions. I will look into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $|R|=n$. The polynomial
$$\prod_{a\in R}(X-a)$$
evaluates to zero. So $X^n\sim$ a polynomial of degree $<n$.
So $X^{n+k}\sim$ a polynomial of degree $<n+k$
and so inductively $\sim$ a polynomial of degree $<n$.

Comment: Great ! I have not thought about such a construction. I was overthinking this problem apparently. Thank you !